# Android virtual device won't start up at all under Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to start the default AVD and it just won't boot up at all. I've waited hours. Overnight. Nothing.

I've played around with the settings too. Tried reinstalling HAXM with 512mb ram as well. Made sure the HAXM RAM and the AVD ram match. Nothing. I've also tried checking "Store a snapshot" rather than "use GPU". Nothing.

This is what the config looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk7Du.png

What should I do?

Comment: Can you post the error or some message displayed in bottom portion of Android Studio ? Because there is no way to know why your AVD won't start up by just looking at the snap shot!!! Have you tried to start the AVD manually as a test case?

Comment: There is no error. The output in Android Studio is: "/Users/samism/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode". Start it manually? Through terminal you mean? Not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `cmd` of your mac, navigate to `/SDKTools` and then run this command `android avd`.
After that the `avd manager` will be on the screen.

For some common emulator configurations, first uncheck the `use host GPU` option..
Next make the `RAM = 768` and `VM Heap = 32`

Try starting the emulator after that ! If that doesn't work, then it means you haven't installed the `avd manager` correctly..

Comment: That didn't work. However, I'm confident that I installed everything correctly. Could it be something else?

Comment: No I didn't. Its the exact same issue.

Comment: Open CMD and navigate to your `/SDKTools` folder, then run this command
`android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID>` replace the `<name>` with a name you want your emulator to have, and `<targetID>` with the api level for that emulator example 8.. see if that opens !! i.e: `android create avd -n myemo -t 08`